# Google Drive folder: Is there a share option to allow comments?

Tags: google-drive

I can Right-click on a Google Drive folder > "Share" > "Advanced" > "Change ..." to get to the screen below.

I can then select "**On** - Anyone with the link". And in the drop-down, there'll be two options:

- "Can organize, add, & edit"
- "Can view only"

I want to also allow anyone with the link to comment on any of the files in this folder (but not allow them to "organize, add, & edit"). However, I don't see any such option. Am I missing something or should I go look for this option somewhere else? (Or is there simply no such option?)

[image]

---

In contrast, with individual files, going through the above steps, I get this screen and drop-down menu with the option "Can comment":

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not that I've found, but I've gotten around this by sharing the folder with them as a viewer, but then selecting all the files in the folder at once, clicking on Sharing, and changing their permissions to Commenter. Since they are already on the access list, it's an easy extra step.